# How to hide overflow icon on action bar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i have added overflow icon on action bar but now for some condition i want to hide it, Is there any way to hide this icon programtically.

Answer (score 1):

For the particular condition you want to hide menus, you can manually call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` in your activity class and in your `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method `setVisible(false);` for all the menu items you have.

For example

```
public void someMethod(){
    if (<somecondition>){
       invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (<somecondition>){
      menu.findItem(R.id.action_one).setVisible(false);
      menu.findItem(R.id.action_two).setVisible(false);
      menu.findItem(R.id.action_three).setVisible(false);
    }else{
      menu.findItem(R.id.action_one).setVisible(true);
      menu.findItem(R.id.action_two).setVisible(true);
      menu.findItem(R.id.action_three).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When you want it to be visible again, again call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` and make sure the condition inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method gets false so that else part is executed.